# Shortcut/program to list the names of open windows on Windows 7+?

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard-shortcuts, productivity

I'm looking for a program for Windows that does something similar to the [tabs outliner extension for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabs-outliner/eggkanocgddhmamlbiijnphhppkpkmkl). I prefer reading the titles of the open windows to a visual representation of them such as is given by alt+tab or win+tab.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this tiny program (22,5 KB) can help - [WinLister](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/winlister.html)!?

Comment: Some more details? Any security assesment?

Comment: @vonbrand: More details would be nice, but yes, NirSoft's utilities are quite trustworthy IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Windows *Task Manager* lists all the open windows that are visible on Taskbar.

[image: Task Manager - Applications tab]
<sub>(source: [malyek.net](https://malyek.net/misc/windows7/super-user/Task%20Manager%20-%20Applications%20tab%20%28cropped%29.png))</sub>

To switch to an application window:

- Double-click its title in the list.
- Right-click an application, and then click **Switch To**.
- Click an application to select it in the list, and then click **Switch To** button at the bottom of Task Manager window.

Task Manager could be launched with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>.